# How to select data with query builder when have many to many relations?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I use Symfony 3.2 and Doctrine Query Builder.
I have ManyToMany Relationship between 
(Users<->roles_users<->Roles)

users(id), 
roles_users(role_id, user_id) and 
roles(id, name).

And want to select only that users where roles.name = 'role_client'. How to do that with query builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine allows you to do an abstraction of the database. You shouldn't think with database table but with entity instead : Your User entity should have a $roles (or maybe a diffrenet name) property so you can use it in your queryBuilder like this:

```
public function findByRoleName(string $roleName)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        // add this to also load the related roles entities
        ->addSelect('r')
        // Where roles is your property name in the User entity
        ->leftJoin('u.roles', 'r')
        ->where('r.name = :roleName')
        ->setParameter('roleName', $roleName)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

I did the join on the property $roles of the User entity : The join table (here roles_users) is totally transparent!

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's work for me. Until now, I could not find a good explanation of how this works. But what about without abstraction? How would it look?

Comment: I call it abstraction because you don't have to care about the join table which is managed by Doctrine. Instead you should only consider your entities and their relations. That's the difference between SQL and D(octrine)QL which allows you to manage entities instead of tables

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method like so in your User Repository :

```
public function findByRole($roleName='role_client')
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                   ->select('u')
                   ->leftJoin('u.role', 'r')
                   ->addSelect('r');

     $query = $query->where('r.name = :rolename')
                   ->setParameter('rolename', $roleName)
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult();

     return $query;

}
```

But be sure that the ORM is properly made between the entities so you can easily join the Role entity with your User entity.

Nose that you may have to change the **'u.role'** part since I do not know how you called it in your User entity.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's work pretty well for me. But what about without abstraction? How would it look?